# Is there anything wrong with using this custom MySQLi escaping PHP function?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wrote a basic wrapper function to escape a string using MySQLi. Is there anything wrong with using this? Is is better than the original? Is it useful?

The function takes two arguments, `$conn`, which is the MySQLi connection, and `&$var`, which is the string you want to escape.

```
function escapestr($conn, &$var){
    $var = $conn->real_escape_string($var);
    return $var;
}
```

Usage:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "my_favourite_db");
$userInput = $_GET["input"]; // value: this is my "inputted" string
$userInput = escapestr($conn, $userInput); // value: this is my \"inputted\" string
```

Or, it can directly update the variable.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "my_favourite_db");
$userInput = $_GET["input"]; // value: this is my "inputted" string
escapestr($conn, $userInput); // value: this is my \"inputted\" string
```

Comment: Completely pointless function. If you're worried about security, you should be using prepared statements anyway.

Comment: Why is `$var` "pass by reference" ___and___ being returned from the function?

Comment: Anything that obscures what you're doing with escaping is bad, and this is a classic example. You also mangle the original string which can cause serious issues if that variable is used twice, so this is somehow worse than the original solution.

Comment: You're all correct. Thanks. I'm going to look into prepared statements. =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong with using this?

Yes. You should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (a.k.a. parameterized statement or parameterized queries) instead of reinventing the wheel.

> Is is better than the original?

All you did is wrap a function in a function. While there are occasionally times where this is useful, this is not one of them.

> Is it useful?

No

Comment: Haha, okay, this makes sense